# Show hidden div (slide) when click on button (change text)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I want to hide some content (#hidden_content) as default. On this page there is a CSS button with text example "Show content".

When click on this button I want the div #hidden_content to show with a slide effect and at the same time the text on the button "Show content" will change to example "Hide content" and when click the content will hide again.

**Button**

```
<a href="" id="button" class="button_style">Show content</a>
```

**Div**

```
<div id="hidden_content">Content</div>
```

**Slide script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Now I want the text on the button so change when click. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd be able to work this one out in about 5 minutes using Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('Hide Content');
  }, function() {
    $(this).text('show Content');
  }).click(function(){
      $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Do you know what to edit if I want to inactivate the slide-function?

Comment: either **commentout the slideToggle in the click function** or remove this **.click(function(){
      $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
  });**

Comment: Becuse it dident "suited" the content to have a slide there.

Comment: then you mean just simple `show()/hide()` or `fadeIn()/fadeOut()` functions.

Comment: **.fadeToggle("slow");** will be another option. if you consider it.

Comment: I just switched slideToggle("slow"); to toggle(); and then it worked. Thanks for you help with the script, now it works!

Comment: @tknickman may be this can help : http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed, Although `.toggle(func, func)` is been removed you can use jQuery Migrate plugin can be used to restore the functionality. [You can get it from here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a `text()` function:

```
$("#button").text("change");
```

You can use this in your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
        $("#button").text("change");
    });
});
```

You can base it on whether or not the content is hidden:

```
$("#button").text($("#hidden_content").is(":hidden")?"Show content":"Hide content");
```

Make sure you use this after the content has been toggled.

Answer (score 0):

From the [slideToggle doc page](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) : you can add a callback which will be executed once the animation is completed

```
$('#hidden_content').sliddeToggle('slow', function(){
  if( $('#hidden_content').is(':hidden') ){
    $('#button').text('Show content');
  } else {
    $('#button').text('Hide content');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools, the event method `toggle()` is removed after version 1.9. (Note: This is the **event method** toggle(), not the **effect method** toggle(). The effect method toggle() stays.)

[Jai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14126157/4627429) is great, so I used his answer and modified it using `if` and `else` instead of `toggle()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'Show Content')
            $(this).text('Hide Content');
        else
            $(this).text('Show Content');
        $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Try it on JSFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/803/).